# What is Ben's teacher's name?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

This is driving me insane! In "The Walking Dead" videogame, what was Ben's teacher's name? (The man who got his leg cut off by Lee.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David Parker.

All of the information about Ben can be found here: http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Ben_Paul